# Concat array of nested documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, shell, aggregate

I am trying to concat some nested documents inside an array using MongoDB shell:

**What I have**

```
"id": 1,
"instructions": [
{"text": "A"},
{"text": "B"},
{"text": "C"}
]
```

**What I want to obtain**

```
"id" : 1
"instructions": "ABC"
```

**What I have tried**

```
{
        $project: {
                "instructions": {
                    $reduce: {
                        input: "$instructions.text",
                        initialValue: [],
                        in:  {
                            $concat : ["$$value", "$$this"]
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

**What I obtain**

```
$concat only supports strings, not array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have tried was correct. But you need to make `initailValue` as `String`, not `array`

```
{
    $project: {
      "instructions": {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$instructions",
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $concat: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this.text"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h9gMDgWkxQM)**